# Hardware software requirements for SAML and OAUTH

Tags: oauth, saml

I am preparing a report on SAML and OAUTH for a comparative study on these two technologies.
I have got a few pages ready describing what SAML and OAUTH can do.

The next thing I need is the hardware and software requirements to implement SSO using SAML and OAUTH.

This would help analyis the costs involved and come to a decision on choosing any of the two technologies.

If you are aware of the H/W and S/W requirements please enumerate them.

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 1):

On the software side, the cost will really depend on what solution you're using. Both technologies have good opensource and commercial implementations (and often, the same product supports both). So, I don't think that the software costs will make a difference.

On the hardware part, SAML is probably a little more power-consuming, because it implies XML parsing, XML digital signature (which needs more resources than a simple digital signature).
But if you have a reasonable number of concurrent users, the raw-power of the most basic servers will be able to absorb the load without problems in each case.

To give some figures, our SAML 2.0 solution (which admittely is performance and not features-oriented) is able to generate ~100 SAML responses per second on my workstation (a low-end sandy bridge pentium). The main factor determining performance is CPU. I/O and memory are somewhat negligeable.

How many authentications per second do you plan to have in production ?